# React Route not working with multiple Urls

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

For my index.js I've got

`import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`

For my App.js I got

`import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";`

My js code in App.js reads like so

```
 <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />
        <Route exact path="/checkout" component={CheckoutPage} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/signin"
          render={() =>
            currentUser ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <CredentialsPage />
          }
        />
      </Switch>
```

Index js is wrapped with BrowserRouter

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The ShopPage component looks like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CollectionsOverview from "../../components/collectionsOverview/CollectionsOverview.component";
import CollectionPage from "../collectionPage/CollectionPage.component";

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => {
  console.log(match.path);
  return (
    <div className="shop-page">
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/test`} component={CollectionPage} />
    </div>
  );
};



export default ShopPage;
```

Now to issue is that whatever I do I cannot make the second route with multiple URLs to load any component, string, or whatever I put there. Match.path is working properly and it displays the first component which is CollectionsOverview, but when I put the second URL after / it always renders an empty screen. (e.g.`${match.path}/whynotloading` ) When I visit that url I am not getting any errors or anything nor the component loads, just the empty screen as I said above. Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think removing exact from ` <Route exact path="/shop" component={ShopPage} />` will do the job

Comment: Thank you, Saed. You are a lifesaver. I was reading the docs about webpack config, react-router doms, lost hours on this simple fix. Thank you so much for taking the time to read the issue.